# cakephp - inbuilt joins are not working

Tags: php, cakephp, join

I have hosted my cakePhp project on hostgator. Its not able to retrieve data of table which is link to other tables. Basically It only pulls data of table on which I am finding But not able to pull data of other tables along with it. It was working on localhost. I have project which has building. Now when i write $this->Projet->find('all'); Iam only getting projects data. Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. Have you used `recursive` ? 2. Check relationships in your `models` ..

Comment: The most probable reason is that there was a problem with uploading the files to the server. Are all the model files there?

Comment: Also, is the hosted database identical to the one you have locally? Are all the tables present and populated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think functionality effects in cake after hosting site or by changing server.

Try this,

1. Check all files uploaded properly at server as Juhana said.
2. Also try to clear your cache of your model from `app\tmp\cache\models`.
3. Check have you use `recursive` before find ?

Comment: I chnaged my cakePHP version from 1.3 to 1.2 and it worked...I really dont know how but it did...thanks all for help

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things i can think of:

1. Check that $this->Project->recursive is not set to -1.
   $this->Project->find('all', array('recursive'=>0));
   http://book.cakephp.org/view/1063/recursive
2. If you're using containable behavior, you will have to list what models to contain with your find, ex. Project belongsTo Site
   $this->Project->find('all', array('contain'=>array('Site'));
3. Check that your models relationships are defined correctly